# ZXing decode image without camera (from gallery) on android

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

I am having problem decoding barcode image from gallery with ZXing library.
This is the code im using:

```
  public static String decode(Bitmap bmp, Activity activity) {

    String text = "";
    if (bmp == null) {
        Log.i("Decoding", "bitmap is null");
    }
    bmp = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    int[] intArray = new int[bmp.getWidth() * bmp.getHeight()];
    bmp.getPixels(intArray, 0, bmp.getWidth(), 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(),
            bmp.getHeight());

    LuminanceSource source = new com.google.zxing.RGBLuminanceSource(
            bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), intArray);
    BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

    Reader reader = new Code128Reader();
    try {
        Result result = reader.decode(bitmap);

        text = result.getText();

    } catch (NotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ChecksumException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FormatException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    Log.i("Decoding", "done");
    if (text != "")
        return text;
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The image im trying to decode works without no problem on http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx (https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9Atk.jpg)

but sadly not with my code. 
Image im trying to decode is JPEG image.

If anyone has any suggestions/fixes to my function i would be very grateful.

Comment: You can check my answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32120988/qr-code-decoding-images-using-zxing-android/36280960#36280960