# QR code decoding images using zxing android

Tags: android, zxing

I am doing a simple application on Android which is the following:

Putting a QR code Image in the Drawable file of the application. By a ButtonClick, it should be decoded and Display the result (using Zxing library).

I have made the same application on Java (the decoding was then using `BufferedImageLuminanceSource` class).

In my android application, I used the `RGBLuminanceSource` class as follows:

```
LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(width, height, pixels)BinaryBitmap binaryBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
```

The problem I am facing here is that: the image has to be too small to be decoded by the android application(and I had to try many sizes to finally got one where the QR code Image is decoded). Meanwhile the same images were decoded easily using the `BufferedImageLuminanceSource` in Java application without any need to be resized.

What to do to avoid this resizing Problem?

Comment: i know this but did not get time now to tell you tomorow will answer you

Comment: Ok Cool! You will save my life.. Waiting for your answer. Thanks @amitsharma

Comment: @amitsharma I am still waiting for your answer. Please help me in that..

Comment: @amitsharma my email is: rawya.abed.enit@gmail.com

Comment: @amitsharma I still don't receive any Thing from you :(

Comment: https://github.com/zxing/zxing,....,,https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/CameraManager.java,,,,,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028735/getting-camera-error-in-zxing-barcode-application

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028735/getting-camera-error-in-zxing-barcode-application

Comment: these are the link of full code of qr code so read codes and implement this is enough for qr code

Comment: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/CaptureActivity.java

Comment: these all github codes so let you implement with your self ......

Comment: if you face some other issue in qr then post here your comments .. i will defiantly aounswers you

Answer (score 7):

Its too late but it can be help to others,

So we can get Qr code Info from Bitmap using Zxing library.

```
 Bitmap generatedQRCode;
    int width = generatedQRCode.getWidth();
    int height = generatedQRCode.getHeight();
    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    generatedQRCode.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

    RGBLuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(width, height, pixels);

    BinaryBitmap binaryBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

    Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
    Result result = null;
    try {
        result = reader.decode(binaryBitmap);
    } catch (NotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ChecksumException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String text = result.getText();
    textViewQRCode.setText(" CONTENT: " + text);
```

Comment: didnt work for me dont know why, cannot recognize code128 barcode :(